# Finding derivative of function from integration

Tags: integration, derivatives

If $F(x)=\int_{1}^{x}f(t) dt$, where $f(t)=\int_{1}^{t^2}\frac{\sqrt{1+u^4}}{u} du$, find $F''(2)$

What I have tried:

- Integration by parts
- Integration by substitution

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: Please share more details on what you tried.

Comment: More details on what I tried: https://i.imgur.com/GRmvODa.png, 
 i.imgur.io/4XFe6Td_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium

Comment: Do not integrate (even if the antiderivative is simple which is the case here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC), $F'(x) = f(x)$. Let $g(x)$ be function such that:

$$
g(x) = \int_1 ^ x \frac{\sqrt{1 + u^4}}{u} du
$$

Therefore $f(x) = g(x^2)$. Since $F''(x) = f'(x)$, we need to obtain $f'(x)$, which is also $(g(x^2))'$. Using the chain rule will get you exactly that, and you can plug in $x=2$ into $F''(x)$.